Kiwi Lad In Need
So I’m based here in New Zealand. I would like to know how I could raise $1000 in a few hours? Sadly without notice I laid off yesterday. On top of that I suffer from depression and anxiety, due to losing my last year to Stage 4 lung Cancer.  I need to raise the funds so I can buy some food and to help me till I find work. I’ve always wanted to work from home, but just haven’t been able to accomplish that yet. So please any ideas, tips would be much appreciated 

You could sell some of your stuff ... ¯\(ツ)/¯

We have no way of knowing what resources and skills you have available, what your local employment opportunities are, etc. Asking the global Internet, in this case, is wasting time you should be putting into finding solutions.

Why do you need to "raise $1000 in a few hours"? What's so urgent? Buying food cannot be a matter of hours, I'm sure you can stay alive for more than a few hours even if hungry. I understand the stress and pressure, but it's always good to reflect and try to analyze the situation rationally. Don't react, respond.

@brhans: Or pawn, if you think the cash flow situation will be corrected quickly. Disadvantage is that you may not get as much for it, advantage is that you have at least some opportunity to buy it back.

Thank you all, for your wise counsel

Anything which offers you a large amount of money in a few hours, no skill required, is going to be either dangerous, unpleasant, expensive, scam, illegal, or some combination of the above. The only good answer, I'm afraid, is to not overcommit and not leave payments until last minute.
Having gotten into this hole, selling or pawning your possessions, or finding a family member or other lender of last resort willing to lend you the money for a short time, is probably the best you are going to do.
The better advice would have been to reduce expenses earlier so you had more savings to provide a short-term buffer, but I grant that folks at the bottom end of the economy don't have that option. If that's you, try various poverty assistance programs, but they're unlikely to be able to respond within hours.

Having dug yourself into this hole.. Care to explain!?

I'd advise against borrowing if you can avoid it, especially if you have no income with which to pay it back.  I also don't think it's realistic to raise the money in a few hours.  Hate to be blunt, but it's unlikely someone with an extra $1000 would give/lend it to you with no repayment in sight.  Here are my ideas...

What are your skills?  Can you offer yourself as a day laborer somewhere?  The pay isn't great but you will be earning what you make, getting experience.  Also I'm no expert but I bet the act of doing something productive can help your mental health.

Do you have family nearby?  If you could stay with them while you earn a little money, your expenses would be less.

Be wary of scams.  You will see work-from-home opportunities with large promised incomes but they are notoriously shady.



Thank you for you guidance and wise words
